Salesforce Formula With Bucket
In Salesforce Report Creator, I need assistance with creating a chat metrics report. Currently, I have the following setup:
Group Rows: Created Date
Group Columns: Chat SLA (a custom bucket field with Wait Time categorized as SLA Met (<=60) and SLA Not Met (>60))
Columns: Chat Transcript ID and # Chat Duration
When I run the report, I have defined only SLA Met and SLA Not Met in the Chat SLA bucket. However, I am also seeing an auto-generated bucket labeled "-",
1, I need a formula to calculate the AHT, I tried this formula SUM(LiveChatTranscript.ChatDuration:SUM)/RowCount but it is also including the counts returned under "-", but I need only the counts from SLA Met and SLA Not Met.
2, I need a formula for calculating SLA, which is SLA Met count / Total Record Count, I tried this formula (SUM(CASE(BucketField_45343300, "SLA Met", 1, 0)) / COUNT(Id)) * 100, but received an Warning: Incorrect parameter type for function 'CASE()'. Expected Object, received Text, For SLA all counts from all 3 buckets should be considered.
Thanks in Advance )
